# Архивация набора строк

Tags: c++, python, алгоритм

Как по набору строк получить другой набор строк такого же размера, но со строками, содержащими идентификаторы исходных строк? Под идентификатором понимается минимальная подстрока исходной строки, начинающаяся с первого символа, по которой можно идентифицировать исходную строку.

Например, для таких строк

```
"I'm Jack"

"I'm Josh"
```

необходимо вернуть

```
"I'm Ja"

"I'm Jo"
```

А для следующих строк

```
"I'm Jack"

"I'm Josh"

"Hello"

"Hell"

"Unique"
```

необходимо вернуть

```
"I'm Ja"

"I'm Jo"

"Hello"

"Hell"

"U"
```

Вопрос скорее по алгоритму, но если есть удобные функции для этого в `C++` или `Python`, то тоже было бы круто их узнать.

Answer (score 0):

Идём по каждой строке с её начала и добавляем в `std::set` сначала первый символ, потом первые 2 и так далее. В конце если размер сета равен кол-ву строк, то всё. Иначе надо удалить те строки, которые лексикографически меньше других (поэтому в сете будут расположены строго раньше) и при этом не встречаются в исходном наборе строк, а также те строки, которые включают в себя другие (в сете строго после искомых строк расположены) и не встречаются в исходном наборе строк. Сам исходный набор строк тоже будет расположен в этом сете, так что это всё будет достаточно быстро.

Answer (score 0):

Построить [trie (бор)](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80), вывести подстроки такие, что конечный элемент является терминальным, или за ним идёт только один терминальный (далее нет разветвлений).
Вероятно, для этого придётся хранить дополнительный признак в узлах trie